# Is it possible to determine if another process has read your memory?

Tags: linux, security, winapi, memory

It isn't so complicated to read another process's memory, and I'm skeptical there is any reliable way of protecting your process's memory from being read by memory inspection tools or developers with the know-how.

However, is there any way to determine if and when your process's memory has been read?

<sup>Bonus points for both Windows and *nix flavor answers.</sup>

Comment: It is possible but it's medium to advanced level. You can set a hardware interrupt for when a particular piece of memory is being read/written, and you tie a callback function to that event. Look up debuggers and hardware interrupts for more on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no. I just had to dump the complete memory of a process some days ago, and the first thing I did, was to suspend the process that should be dumped. As the stopped process has no control over its own restart, there is no guarantee that it can continue afterwards, so there is no way that it could reliable check whether it was dumped or not.

There are several approaches that are used, esp in the copy-protection area, like crypting memory addresses, spawning several other process to guard the orignial process, and several other tricks but which are nothing more than that: tricks. As long as the hardware does not fully encrypt everything and does inside the cpu itself without anbybody else giving access to it the there is always a way to read the memory without letting the cpu know it (e.g. intels TPM is a first towards this direction).

E.g. one possible attack to get passwords in embedded devices is the following:
To get the password in the ram, the device is opened (while running), the dram chips are frozen and then connected to a different device (and the original is shut down). The frozen state allows the chips to retain their electric state some secs longer without refresh - enough time to connect them else where and read afterwards everything out. No program could detect such a thing. Only way around is the above mentioned: the content on the chips itself must be encoded.